# compute index of vector field $v_1: (x, y) \rightarrow (-y, x)$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I'm trying to compute the index of the vector field,

$$
 v_1: (x, y) \rightarrow (-y, x) 
$$

at the singularity $(0,0)$.

Because, $(0, 0)$ is a singularity of that vector field, the index is given by,

$$
  \iota_{(0,0)} := \text{deg}(\hat{v}_1) \in \mathbb{Z}
$$

where,
$$
  \hat{v}: \partial B((0,0), \epsilon) \subset S^1 \rightarrow S^1, \quad x \rightarrow \frac{v(x)}{||v(x)||}
$$

For our vector field $v_1$, let $x = \cos(\theta)$, $y = \sin(\theta)$. Then we have,
$$
  v_1: (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)) \rightarrow (- \sin(\theta), \cos(\theta))
$$

And,

$$
  \hat{v}_1: (\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)) \rightarrow (- \sin(\theta), \cos(\theta))
$$

The total derivative of $\hat{v}_1$ is given by,
$$
  d\hat{v}_1 : T_{(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))} S^1 \rightarrow T_{(- \sin(\theta), \cos(\theta))} S^1, \quad \langle (-\sin(\theta), \cos(\theta)) \rangle \rightarrow \langle (-\cos(\theta), -\sin(\theta)) \rangle
$$

Then,
$$
  deg(\hat{v}_1) = \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} \text{sign}(\text{det}(d\hat{v}_1))
$$

How can I do from there ? I should set an orientation on the starting tangent plane ?

Comment: I think you misunderstood the definition of the degree. You are not calculating the degree at the circle, but at the origin directly.

Comment: Your notation is inconsistent. You have to choose a regular value $y$ of $\hat v_1$. In this case, every point $y$ in the circle will be such a regular value. Then you have to look at all the preimages $x$. There will be exactly one. Now what?